# Migrating JSPs in Spring boot app to use angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, hybrid

I'm working on spring boot project that uses JSPs for view. Since it's a big project, we'll migrating couple of views with each release and not all at once. So angular code will be part of war file

I've referred these two articles but not able to load angular app:
https://medium.com/@majdasab/integrating-an-angular-project-with-spring-boot-e3a043b7307b

https://medium.com/@frithjof.hoppe/setup-a-single-angular-6-and-spring-boot-project-with-maven-ac656c7753ff

I'm new to angular, so any pointers will be appreciated.

**Update:**
Looking at few comments below, I see there may be some confusion, so adding few points

1. I want to deploy a war file (no jar / embedded server)
2. Angular code has to be part of WAR, so can be served on same port
3. Application will contain few pages that are **served using angular and few will remain JSPs** (as mentioned above we'll be migrating couple of pages in each release)

Comment: Read this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-angular-web

Answer (score 1):

You could just add the angular app into `webapp` package under `main` and add spring configuration file to add build config. Communication can be done using REST calls.
You might need to add CORS configuration to avoid API calls getting blocked.

Comment: I thought you wanted a WAR deployment?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's stated in the question that he wants everything to be in a war file

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I missed that.

Comment: @AravindSaiVellappat I have tried this approach from mentioned articles above, can you please elaborate your approach or point to some resource ?

Comment: @GauravPingale Use https://www.jhipster.tech/ to create a sample project. It has the features you are looking for. You can use it directly or use it to understand the structure. I hope this helps.